# Sequelize one-to-many self-reference table, how to find parent, parent of parent, parent of parent of parent... and so on?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

So basically I have a model `DriveObject` that is self-referencing with a foreign key `parentId`

I am using `express` and `node.js` for backend.

Here is how I defined the association in the code:

```
driveObject.hasMany(driveObject, { as: 'Children', foreignKey: 'parentId' });
driveObject.belongsTo(driveObject, { as: 'Parent', foreignKey: 'parentId' });
```

`DriveObject` can play the role of a folder.

Same as a classic directory, it can have one parent folder and many children.

If it's in the root / does not have a parent, then `parentId` is `null`.

If it has a parent, then `parentId` is equal to the `id` of the parent.

Let's assume:

```
  - Parent Folder: (id: 1, parentId: null)
  | - Child Folder 1: (id: 3, parentId: 1)
    | - Child Folder 2: (id: 8, parentId: 3)
```

How can I ask `sequelize` to find Child Folder 2, its parent (Child Folder 1), and also the parent of its parent (Parent Folder), so basically until reaching a `DriveObject` that has a `parentId` which is null.

I am trying to find a solution that minimizes the number of requests to the database. This is important.

If it's not possible with the current association, how can I solve this? Should I add another table? Is there a package that solves this?

Looking forward to your answers and suggestions!

Comment: any solution should test for cycles or you could go infinite

Comment: See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal) for recursive hierarchies in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use with recursive to get all nodes of your tree structure.
**the example in MySQL**:

```
WITH recursive ancestor AS (SELECT table.id, table.ruta, table.id_parent FROM table where table.id = @your_id UNION SELECT  table.id, table.ruta, table.id_parent FROM table,ancestor where table.id = ancestor.id_parent ) SELECT * from ancestor;
```

this query get all the three structure for the id that you find.
I wish this can help you to get a idea or if you can execute a native query this could work.

if you want a more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

and if you want all tree only remove the first where.

Comment: Thank you! Changed the variables to what I have and used sequelize.query() and it worked!